# Android - Firebase order by value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node with a list of user scores in a Firebase DB, I would like to order the list from highest to lowest and show only the top 10 scores:

My leaderboard node:

```
leader_board
 -$week_id
   -$user_id: score
```

And my java code is as follows:

```
Query leader_board_query = leader_board_reference.child(week_id).orderByValue().limitToLast(10);
```

For some odd reason, it always orders from lowest to highest. I have tried using `limitToFirst(10)` and nothing changes, please help

Comment: Updated answer, please report back if it works (or doesn't work) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this painful problem. All I had to do was alter my recyclerview layout a bit by adding the following lines of codes to its layout manager.

```
LinearLayoutManager layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
layout_manager.setReverseLayout(true);
layout_manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

The list got ordered in reverse which is resulted in ordering from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 5):

`orderByValue()` will always order by ascending order.

You can use `limitToLast()` to get only the last section of the sorted items then you **have to** revert the items programmatically.

Example dataset:

```
1, 3, 8, 9, 0, 5, 4, 7, 6, 2
```

`orderByValue().limitToFirst(3)` should return `0, 1, 2`

`orderByValue().limitToLast(3)` should return `7, 8, 9`, and then you revert the array to get `9, 8, 7`.

**Note:** This is all untested, please report back with results ;)

Comment: Thanks @Antoine, i'll give it a try just now and report back